# Remove standard ylabel from column name in pandas boxplot

Tags: pandas, layout, label, boxplot, yaxis

How do I remove the column name (R) as ylabel from the plot below:

[image]

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize= (20, 7.5))
bp = df_seas_true.boxplot(column= 'R', vert= False, ax= ax, grid= False);
ax.set_ylabel(' ')
ax.set_xlabel('R')
```

The ax.set_ylabel(' ') does not work...

Regards,

Dante

Comment: Change bp to ax and use `ax.set_yticklabels([])`

Comment: `R` is not `ylabel` it's an `yticklabel` i.e. `R` is representing that boxplot and not the axis.